# Proper method of using store as single source of data across siblings, children, etc

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have done a few different tutorials and built some smaller projects with React/Redux and I am having some confusion about the proper method of using Redux to store and retrieve data. Here is how the tutorials seem to go about using the store.

1. Values are read from a data and stored into the store.
2. Connect and MapStateToProps are then used to place the data into the props
3. If the data has to be manipulated on the page, those props are placed into the state
4. SetState is used to update the state

This seems like a wildly obtuse method of using a single source of data when what I expected was to simply be able to:

1. Import the store through some method
2. Use that data to display items
3. Manipulate the store on the component while updating the database

The problem that I am running into now is that when a sibling updates data, the store updates, but not the sibling component. The process of mapping the store to the props and then remapping them to the state is obviously the problem and I just can't believe that this is the preferred method. What am I missing here?

Here is a sibling component that is failing to update when the Redux store is changed in a sibling. The this.state.question.type is changed and that change does not prompt this component to update. It makes me think that there simply has to be a better way to interact with the store. Or maybe I have a problem somewhere else? Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


// Import CSS
import './editQuestionStyle.css';
import '../mainCSS.css';


// Import Bootstrap Items
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import InputGroup from 'react-bootstrap/InputGroup';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';

// Font Awesome Items
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlusCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


// Action creators
import { editQuestion } from '../../store/actions/questions';




class AnswerOptions extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state={};
                this.state.question = props.question;
        }
        
        handleClick = (e)=>{
            this.setState(prevState=>({
                question : { 
                    ...prevState.question,
                    answerOptions : 
                        prevState.question.answerOptions.concat('Answer Option')
                }
            }));
        }


        render(){

            return (

                <div>
                <Row className="mt-large mb-3 ml-large mr-large text-center">

                    <Col sm={2}>
                        <div className="lead">
                            Answer Options
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle}    
                                                            className="ml-small mt-tiny hover-me easy-text" 
                                                            onClick={()=>{this.handleClick()} } />
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    {this.state &&
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm={4}>
                                <Container>
                                    {this.state.question.answerOptions.length==0 ? <div className="center-me">Click plus to add option</div> : ''}

                                        {this.state.question.answerOptions.map((answerOption, index) => (
                                            <div>
                                                <InputGroup key="index" className="mb-3 width-175 center-me">
                                                    
                                                    {this.state.question.type=='Select' ? <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                                        <InputGroup.Radio aria-label="Correct Answer" />
                                                    </InputGroup.Prepend>:''}

                                                    <FormControl
                                                        placeholder="Enter Input"
                                                        aria-label="Tag Name"
                                                        aria-describedby="email"
                                                        ref = {this.tag+""+index}
                                                        onChange={()=>{}}
                                                    />  
                                                </InputGroup>
                                            </div>

                                        ))}
                                </Container>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={8}>
                                <p className="text-justify">For questions where the user selects the answer, the options you enter here will be presented to them and players must choose the option you mark as correct.</p>
                                <p className="text-justify">For questions where the user enters the answer, the options you enter here can be variations on the correct answer such as misspellings. If what the user enters matches any of the values entered, the answer will be marked as correct.</p>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>}

                </Row>

                </div>
            ) 
        }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps)=>{
    const questionId = ownProps.questionId;
    const questions = state.firestore.data.questions;
    const question = questions ? questions[questionId] : null;
    return {
        question:question,
        questionId : questionId
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
                editQuestion: (question, questionId) => dispatch(editQuestion(question, questionId))
        }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AnswerOptions);
```

Comment: Why did you initialize local state (`this.state.question = props.question`) in constructor ?

Comment: The store is brought into the component through the mapStateToProps command. I need to manipulate those items. Should I simply be using the props and then let SetState change the store?

Comment: I should add that this confused me too and is the basis for the question. I don't understand the point of a Redux store if you are just going to move that data to a local state object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you initialize the local state with the `props.question` ? You don't have to do such a thing. Your `render()` method is use the local state which was one time initialized with the redux store values in the constructor. After that even your siblings are update the store, there is no reason to update the UI since you don't directly use the values from `mapStateToProps`, instead you use local state which was initialized when the component class is created.

Let the actions\dispatchers to update the redux store & use the `props.question` directly in `render()` method.

In `handleClick` you are not `dispatch` new values to the store. It is just update the local state. Instead of doing that, you should call the `dispatcher` or the `action` which is responsible for update the related `reducer`. Once you do that `props.question` will changed & will force to re render the necessary parts.

And finally, as the Dan Abramov said,

> "I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems
> with vanilla React."

Also, according to Pete Hunt,

> "You'll know when you need Flux. If you aren't sure if you need it,
> you don't need it."

If you don't understand the Redux, this is one of the best explanation you can find https://youtu.be/3sjMRS1gJys

Please note that `react-redux` is just a adapter to use Redux with React.

And Finally I would encourage you to use functional components with hooks which will completely remove the mess of Higher order components (`connect`) , `mapStateToPros` & `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: Thanks. In my experience, there is no real need for Redux in most applications. I was just brushing up on it and got confused by a tutorial. I changed the code to simply reflect the props and then manipulate the store and the databases directly. Works well now. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something.